# Problem identifying this encoding schematic into plain text

Tags: cryptography, encoding

Im really new to all of this i'd like some insight.
the encoding scheme looks like this

```
e0b7 e51f a24f 2ee8 f950 ecc4 d46b 6b3b 11bd 1930 ccb0 3c9f ecf5 368d f570 c72d a37e 47a6 bf03 2cf4 947c e913 a32a 5a80 379f
```

If i knew what format this is i'd be able to get it into plane text. thats all i need. simple question i hope.

Comment: Do you have any indications about the plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module codecs from python can do that for you

```
print(codecs.decode("707974686f6e2d666f72756d2e696f", "hex"))
```